# WordPress Gutenberg page editor white screen of death

Tags: wordpress

I have been using Gutenberg editor for a while now but now when I want to edit my website pages using Gutenberg page editor the editor shows white background or screen of death.

I have tried it on different browsers all to no avail
I have turned on debug mode on the server side and fixed all the depreciation errors but the pro blew still exit.

please help

thanks

Comment: The issue has be resolved after a long day.
The error was from a plugin called REST API Helper.
I have to disable it and boom it worked.